# MySQL - How to limit query results based on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `users` table, a `posts` table, and a search feature that queries MySQL for posts.

I want it to return all posts for 100 specific users (with a maximum of 6 posts per user).

I have a column called `user_id` on the `posts` table which is a foreign key.

Right now I can return all posts for those users like this:

```
SELECT id FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4 .... 98,99,100);
```

However many of these users have hundreds of posts. I want to cap it at 6 per user. How can I add such a constraint to my query?

I am using MySQL version 8.0.15

Comment: You can use `LIMIT`.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Thank you but I don't think you understood my question correctly. I know how to limit the total number of posts using `LIMIT`. I want to limit the number of posts per user to 6.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 8.0.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ROW_NUMBER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800)(MySQL 8.0+) could be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY col_time DESC) AS rn
                                                   -- taking the newest posts
  FROM posts 
  WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4 .... 98,99,100)
) sub
WHERE rn <= 6;
```

Comment: Waiting another minute to accept this as the correct answer, but this worked like a charm in no time flat. Perfect!

Comment: This brought my query time down to 0.5 seconds from about ~12 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Lukasz's answer is fine.  But, you don't need to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE p.user_id IN (1,2,3,4 .... 98,99,100) AND
      p.col_time >= ALL (SELECT p2.col_time
                         FROM posts p2
                         WHERE p2.user_id = p.user_id
                         ORDER BY p2.col_time DESC
                         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
                        );
```

(Note:  The `ALL` handles the case when there are fewer than 6 posts for the user.)

With an index on `posts(user_id, col_time)`, it would be interesting to know if this is faster or slower than `ROW_NUMBER()`.